# Per-user tag cloud in PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking to implement a per-user tag/interest cloud feature to a website I am making.

Each user has a profile page, and on said page a tag cloud of their preselected interests will be displayed. Each user can type their interests comma delimitated, with suggestions if such a tag has been used before or creation if it doesn't exist. Interests will be things such as Music Genres, Hobbies etc.

I'd like to also add basic features such as comparing users tag clouds (shared tags) for finding users that are 'compatible' according to their cloud.

I could use help with the logistics of the database to achieve this. I understand simple database design, but I can't wrap my head around design for the above.

At the moment the database is one single table, with ID/Username/Password/Verification (the last a key for email verification).

The only idea I have come up with for the tag cloud db is two tables - one called tags with a tagid and tagname field, and another users_tags with a tagid and userid field, and an entry for every single tag a user has. However I am unsure if this is best practice.

Hope someone can give me some direction on all this - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

having a table with userid and tagid only sounds like the best route for this.

to find "compatible" users as you mention you can just run a query similar to

```
SELECT 
   ut.userid, COUNT(*) ct 
FROM 
   user_tags ut 
WHERE 
   ut.tagid IN (SELECT uta.tagid FROM user_tags uta WHERE uta.userid=24 ) 
GROUP BY ut.userid ORDER BY ct DESC;
```

note that the above query will also return the original user, but it's much more efficient than removing him from the query.

Comment: Agree - except for "...much more efficient" - excluding the original account wil not impact performance / efficiency. OTOH using an inner join rather than a sub query is likely to improve performance a lot.

Comment: symcbean, how could I do this using an inner join? could you expand a little? thanks